# Deprecated warning on method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, ruby-on-rails-4

I am currently building a friendship requests model in Rails which uses the following code:

```
Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :user  
  belongs_to :friend, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "friend_id"
  validates_presence_of :user_id, :friend_id  
end
```

Upon looking up the `:class_name` method on the APIdock website, I get a warning saying *this method is deprecated*:

> **Method deprecated or moved**
>
> This method is deprecated or moved on the latest stable version. The
>   last existing version (v2.3.8) is shown here.
>
> http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/class_name/class

Should I be concerned about using this in my application?

Comment: What link says that `class_name` is deprecated?

Comment: What exactly is the problem here?

Comment: Can you share the link where it says it is deprecated?

Comment: Which version of rails are you using?

Comment: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/class_name/class >>

Comment: why we use :class_name ??

Comment: Why doesnt anybody read the big blue box that says 'deprecated **_or moved_**'????

Comment: you are looking in the wrong place. you are using `:class_name` as an option to a `belongs_to`. that IS NOT the method documentation you are looking at. if you want to see the options that you can use in rails4 go to http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to worry about this. The method is **not** deprecated in the public Rails API.

The warning you see on the APIdock website means that `class_name` was moved internally to a different class. It went from `ActiveRecord::Base` to `ActiveRecord::Reflection::MacroReflection`.